# Laravel + VueJS + Axios Get Request Not Working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, get, axios

I am new to Vue and Laravel. I want get users from the database with Axios. But it doesn't work. Axios post request works fine but get request not work. Please help me.

Thanks.
*

**UserController.php**

```
    public function index()
    {
        
        return User::latest()->paginate(10);

    }
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::apiResources(['user' => 'App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController']);
```

**Users.vue**

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      data(){
        return{
          users : {},
          form: new Form({
            name: '',
            email:'',
            password: '',
            type: '',
            bio: '',
            photo: '',
          })
        }
      },
      methods:{
        loadUsers(){
          console.log('Load user');
          axios.get("api/user").then(({data})  => (this.users = data.data));
        },
      
        createUser(){
          this.form.post('api/user')
        }
      },
        created() {
            this.loadUsers();
        }

    }
</script>
```

[Route List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny6Oc.png)

[Function successfully call but it didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAVj7.png)

[Vue Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyyzI.png)

[Network1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGO9o.png)

[Network2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frV4M.png)

Comment: try `dd(User::latest()->paginate(10));` in your `index` function.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Thanks for answer, but  there was no change i don't see dd function answer on screen. I think axios get request not call index function. But i checking on route list, routes are ok.

Comment: You will see output in `network` section of `devtools`, just check whether it is returning the data you want or not. If so, then you can check front or backend code.

Comment: I added two images named Network1 Network2 on the answer. I think requests work fine but return the HTML page.

Comment: you should have selected the `api/user` xhr on left hand side and then `response` tab on right hand side

Comment: @JitendraYadav I am sorry. I am changed images can you check?

Comment: This doesn't seem to call the actual function that is mapped

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I found my problem. My problem one line in the web.php file.

**Old-Web.php**

```
    Route::get('{path}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->where('path','.*');
```

**New-Web.php**

```
    Route::get('{path}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->where('/path','([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

I changed this line and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, I solved this problem using the new routing system that laravel 8 offers. I put the resource Route like this:

```
Route::group(
  [
      'middleware' => 'api',
      'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers',
  ],
  function ($router) {
      Route::resource('user', 'API\UserController');
  }
);
```